# remove inline scripts from the_content() produced by plugins?

Tags: javascript, content, filters

hey guys,
any idea how I could filter all inline javascripts from the content()?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but I imagine

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_kses_post');
```

will scrub it good. Might need playing with priority.

Comment: thank you, I'll give it a try. A lot of plugins are creating script tags at the bottom of my <bod> tag. Any idea how to prevent that plugins do that?

Comment: @mathiregister likely they are either echoing them or queuing them for footer. Hard to say without looking at specific code. Please ask that as separate question with details like specific plugins you use.

Comment: @mathiregister - You could print out a list of the filters on `the_content`, and remove them in groups or one at a time, to see which ones(if any) get rid of the scripts you're having an issue with. I could add an example to Rarst's answer (if that's ok with Rarst?) of printing out the functions attached to that hook.

Comment: @t31os I think that would be pretty good answer on its own?

Comment: Sure it could be, but you've already addressed the original question, this is more an additional to the solution, which is why i thought it might be appropriate to add it to the existing answer. I don't mind really, i'll add an answer if you prefer... :)

Comment: @t31os nah, it's perfectly fine to add another answer. It could always be more fitting or something, it's not uncommon for accepted answer to change in light of new info.